Docker is not running without sudo privilage in Ubuntu 24.04
I have created docker group in my system
sudo groupadd docker
and added current user there:
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
Applied the new group membership without logging out
newgrp docker
Restarted docker
sudo systemctl restart docker
When I do:
docker ps it shows the same result
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///home/user/.docker/desktop/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running? 
Any help would be appreciated?
I have tried to change permissions but I am having same result. I also checked the file
unix:///home/user/.docker/desktop/docker.sock, that file does not exist.

It doesn't look like a permission issue to me. But normally the docker socket is located at /var/run/docker.sock and not at /home/user/.docker/desktop/docker.sock as you have.

That path refers to Docker Desktop.  That runs a hidden Linux VM, and it's unnecessary on a native-Linux host.  You do need to undo a bit of its configuration if you uninstall it, which is described in the linked question.

I have uninstalled the docker and all related dependencies, and still seeing the same result. But after running following command it fixed my error:
docker context use default
